# Modelling Poisson "Point" Process and data transmission with Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process, point-processes

If a Poisson Point Process (PPP) $\Phi_c$ with density $\lambda_c$ (points/m$^2$) distributed over 2D plane. 
These points depict the cellular nodes.

Consider every node transmit data on the uplink transmission. This data transmission is random and is modeled as a Poisson process. The data transmission rate is $\lambda_u$ packets/sec each node.

Can we now model the new PPP $\Phi'_c$ with intensity $\lambda'_c = \lambda_c\times\lambda_u$ ?

Comment: Any one on this, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think this seems more like clustering problem. I am no expert, but the link [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2769740/modelling-poisson-point-process-and-data-transmission-with-poisson-process) may help you.